# Can TFServer be connected to TFService?

Tags: azure-devops

So I've got Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 3 installed and ready to go and planned on using Git. However, it wasn't until that point that I realized there was a Distinction between Team Foundation **Server** and Team Foundation **Service** in such a way that the **Service** wasn't merely a part of the **Server**.

I could just use Team Foundation **Service** but the problem is I had hoped to do automated deployments to certain machines on our intranet. Server would obviously have access to that box and Service obviously does not.

Is there a way to have TF **Server** talk to TF **Service** in order to pull the source and do builds/deployments?

I'd really rather not have to use TFVC and would much prefer git. I understand you can have the build agent run from source from a different location - but that would still be the Server's build agent connecting to the Service's Git which still won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* install a local Team Foundation Server 2012 Build Controller + Agent on your on-premise systems and have it trigger a build and deployment from changes submitted to the Team Foundation Service projects that are using TFVC.

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330987(v=vs.110).aspx#hosted

You *can* install a local Team Foundation Server 2013 Preview Build Controller + Agent on your on-premise systems and have it trigger a build and deployment from changes submitted to Team Foundation Service projects regardless of the source control type used (TFVC and GIT)

You *cannot* connect a Team Foundation Server (Source Control, Work Item Tracking) to the Team Foundation Service.

Comment: I think that's still the server connecting to git, is it not?

Comment: No the server can connect to TFS Source Control. Team Build 2012 doesn't support Git. Use the scenario **Use an on-premises build controller**

Comment: You'll need to use the Team Foundation Server 2013 Preview Build controller+Agent to build against Git. I haven't tested whether you can use that to connect to a Team Foundation Service project.

Comment: Just had it confirmed. Team Build 2013 Preview should be able to build against Git from an on-premise machine. You can then use that build to trigger a powershell script of something else to cause the deployment to be triggered. InRelease will probably also fill this gap: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/07/10/inrelease-for-visual-studio-2013-preview-now-available.aspx